# How to find minimum value in a column based on condition in an another column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
Number  Req Response 
0       3    6
1       5    0
2       33   4
3       15   3
4       12   2
```

I would like to identify minimum 'Response' value before the 'Req' is 15.

i tried the below code:

```
min_val=[]
for row in range(len(df)):
#if the next row of 'Req' contains 15, append the current row value of'Response'
  if(df[row+1].loc[df[row+1]['Req'] == 15]): 
         min_val.append(df['Response'].min())
  else:
         min_val.append(0)
```

I get 'invalid type comparison' error.

I expect the below output:

```
Min value of df['Response'] is: 0
```

Comment: Will 15 always be present in `Req`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible value `15` is not in data, use general solution:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
out = df.loc[df.Req.eq(15)[::-1].cumsum().ne(0), 'Response'].sort_values()
print (out)
1    0
3    3
2    4
0    6
Name: Response, dtype: int64

print (next(iter(out), 'no match'))
0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.Req.eq(15))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Req, dtype: bool

print (df.Req.eq(15)[::-1])
4    False
3     True
2    False
1    False
0    False
Name: Req, dtype: bool

print (df.Req.eq(15)[::-1].cumsum())
4    0
3    1
2    1
1    1
0    1
Name: Req, dtype: int32

print (df.Req.eq(15)[::-1].cumsum().ne(0))
4    False
3     True
2     True
1     True
0     True
Name: Req, dtype: bool
```

Test with not matched value:

```
print (df)
   Number  Req  Response
0       0    3         6
1       1    5         0
2       2   33         4
3       3  150         3
4       4   12         2


df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
out = df.loc[df.Req.eq(15)[::-1].cumsum().ne(0), 'Response'].sort_values()
print (out)
Series([], Name: Response, dtype: int64)

print (next(iter(out), 'no match'))
no match
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. But i get a 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' error for this.

Comment: @hakuna_code - Create default index - `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: perfect! Thank you..it worked.. looks like there were some duplicates in the index

Answer (score 2):

One way could be using `idxmax` to find the first index where `Req` is equal to `15`, use the result to index the dataframe and take the minimum `Response`:

```
df.loc[:df.Req.eq(15).idxmax(), 'Response'].min()
# 0
```

---

Where:

```
df.Req.eq(15)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Req, dtype: bool
```

And the `idxmax` will return the index of the first `True` occurrence, in this case `3`.

Comment: `idxmax` is a bit dangerous, if no `15` value it return incorrectly first value..